# Javafx application can not launch when migrating from java 7u21 to higher version

Tags: java, javafx, version

I'm taking over this guy application and he left me pretty much nothing, even the coding is not commented. With luck (and a bit of time), I was able to improve the app and make it run like a charm on my computer.

But I'm having a problem, which is annoying and prevent me from upgrading the app. My app can run fine on any machines installed with java version 1.7.0_21, but when I update to newer version (for now it's 1.7.0_60), the app can not run, it just keeps having this stupid error and I can not do anything to fix it.

Here is the error log:

```
RenderJob.run: internal exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext.nSetBlendEnabled(JZ
Z)I
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext.nSetBlendEnabled(Native Method)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DContext.initState(D3DContext.java:84)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.<init>(D3DResourceFactory.java:5
7)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.createResourceFactory(D3DPipeline.java:
150)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getD3DResourceFactory(D3DPipeline.java:
156)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.findDefaultResourceFactory(D3DPipeline.
java:182)
at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getDefaultResourceFactory(D3DPipeline.j
ava:204)
at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.getDefaultResourceFactory(GraphicsPipe
line.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$3.run(QuantumRenderer.java:
143)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Quantu
mRenderer.java:98)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found another issue which is similar
[Unable to deploy JavaFX applicaiton with external libraries in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815835/unable-to-deploy-javafx-applicaiton-with-external-libraries-in-a-jar)
but I can not apply that in my case since this program/framework need to run from a .bat file (which is command line actually) to creat a bunch of report files and folders.

Comment: do you have jars of javafx added to the system path or classpath? If so remove the same.

Comment: yes I do have an external lib folder, but if I remove any, the app won't work, because I already told my app where to look for the classpath in the run command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wich JavaFX version you have attached to your app?
I suspect the attached JavaFX version is not compatible with 1.7.0_60. I had some equal issues with that.
But the exception is new to me (its some internal prism stuff)

Comment: I can't believe I missed this thing, I mean I was surfing through all my external lib files and update them to the latest version for best compatibility with 1.7.0_60, but I just clearly missed this one terribly. So the simple solution is to go to the installation folder on that problematic machine and copy/replace the jfxrt.jar file to my external lib folder. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that the JFXRT jar is tightly coupled to the JRE/JDK version.update that it comes bundled with (in the case of oracles jvm). This means that the application needs to be ran on a jvm version.update as it was pulled from. You should be able to work around this by using the prescribed methods of building found here, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm.

Comment: The method I've found the most success with has been bundling the needed jre with the application. Its not the cleanest or even close to the best, but its most certainly the easiest.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got the problem solved by updating my jfxrt.jar file to the local version of the machine I was running from. Sometimes problem comes from some minor steps that we missed.